# Embed linux terminal on website(I'm using flask)

Tags: linux, web, flask, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to figure out how to embed a running linux terminal on my webpage. For example, placing a image file of a ubuntu machine on my webpage so you can type just as if at your local machine.  I don't really want to do so via ssh but my web development is limited so I'm looking for advice as well.

Thanks!

[Here is from cisco net acad courses, this is the best way to describe it, a ubuntu box online that users can interact with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZuJt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Can you provide more examples and the attempts you've made?

Comment: I added a image of what I am trying to describe. Right now, Im trying out shellinabox but figured to ask the question before i'm running down the wrong road. Thanks